# Determining the number of files in each level in RocksDB

Tags: rocksdb

By default, RocksDB sets `target_file_size_base` to `64 MB` and `target_file_size_multiplier` to `1`. The comments in the code mention that:

> Target file size for level L can be calculated by `target_file_size_base * (target_file_size_multiplier ^ (L-1))`. By default `target_file_size_multiplier` is 1, which means by default files in different levels will have similar size.

However, when `target_file_size_multiplier` is `1`, the target file size for a level will be equal to `target_file_size_base` so how will the number of files per level be determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the size of SST files in each layer is the same as you noticed since `target_file_size_multiplier` is 1. But there is another pair of parameters `max_bytes_for_level_base` (Default: 256M) and `max_bytes_for_level_multiplier` (Default: 10). Every layer therefore has `((max_bytes_for_level_base) * (max_bytes_for_level_multiplier ^ (L-1))) / (target_file_size_base * (target_file_size_multiplier ^ (L-1)))` files. For example, L1 has 256MB / 64MB = 4 SST files, and L2 has 4 * 10 = 40 files. So as so on.